# Engine Limited HTML and CSS - How Can I Create This Effect from This URL?

Tags: html, css

Still learning the ropes for article writing on wiki webpages and I have been searching for two days for means of reproducing this effect that I know is possible because this URL shows it functional on a site using the same engine I am, which is Gamepedia.

Below is the link with the effect I am trying to replicate.

```
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Iron_sword
```

Now a screenshot showing exactly what I'm hoping to accomplish. This effect in access to any image I place in any table, to hover and show information in this similar manner.

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/189ms6xsl44orhv/demonstration.png?dl=0
```

I really have no idea where to start. I have access to the CSS articles. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

More useful links with the templates and CSS media wiki pages for this example:

```
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Template:Item
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Template:Grid
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/MediaWiki:Hydra.css
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/MediaWiki:Common.css
```

EDIT:
I am still not 100% sure how it is doing that, but it must be possible since it is on the same engine. It appears to be a     mouseover that displays a custom font-family with a bordered background using a custom choice of colors. It can even have multiple colors of text and the window background that shows can be significantly larger if desired. I don't wish to have the entire Grid or Item template in operation on the Wiki I am looking to improve voluntarily, I simply would like some help learning how I can do that     mouseover technique.

I have provided the involved style sheets above for the functional example and politely request for assistance in learning what code I can bring from it over to the other Gamepedia Wiki for the precise effect I'm after, not the entire templates. I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and no one I have contacted has been able to help with this, as it must be more complex than I thought it would be. There has got to be a genius out there who knows the exact innards of this scenario, please help!

EDIT Engine Properties:
Cannot use: Javascript
Can use: CSS
Can use: Some HTML

Comment: Search for "jQuery tooltip" that should start you on your way.  Also when making posts be more detailed and supply the code.

Comment: I have done some research on jQuery tooltip and it is leading me to information that is a bit beyond my grasp at this time, kind sir.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done with some simple Javascript. It's very well documented and a simple search would provide you all the information you need to help setting it up.

But, you said you wanted to do this in pure CSS (which is probably what I would do).

Check out this [example I created here](http://jsfiddle.net/8okwd99d/).

Basically you can add the hover text as a `span` element inside another element (in this case`p`), like so:

```
<p>Hover here.<span>Some text appears!</span></p>
```

Then, define styles for this `span` element, setting a `relative` `position`, and hiding the element when the page initially loads:

```
span {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    /* Change the relative positioning of the overlay*/
    left: 20px;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Then, simply show it on hover:

```
p:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

You can make this implementation as similar to the linked example you provided. For example, could go find a pixel font and render the contents in the `span` in that font.

This should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you're injecting this into a website of some kind, you should assign ids for everything or else it will conflict with the current layout of the site and break it.

Comment: This is a very simple CSS concept that I suggest you research. It would become something like `#hover-item {}` and `#hover-item:hover {}`.

Comment: I have the code in
    #hover-item span { }
and
    #hover-item p:hover { }
And for the (p)(span) result I get Hover here.Some text appears! with no hovering effect whatsoever. Bright side, the code I just provided seems to not break the website, which is great.